# How to pass an array of string to dbus in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, dbus, pyqt5, qt5.4

I'm trying to make a dbus call using python3.4 and pyqt5.4 to a java-written daemon, the signature of the daemon for the method I'm calling is `asa{sv}`

The call I'm doing is

```
fpiudaemon = QDBusInterface("it.libersoft.FirmapiuDInterface", "/it/libersoft/FirmapiuD", interface='it.libersoft.FirmapiuDInterface' , parent=None)
result = fpiudaemon.call('sign',filepath,options)
```

Where

```
print (filepath) -> ['/home/svalo/programmi/devel/pythondeps']
print (options) -> {'pin': '12345678', 'outdir': '/home/svalo/programmi/devel/firmapiu-gui'}

print(type(filepath)) -> <class 'list'>
print(type(options)) -> <class 'dict'>
```

However when I monitor dbus what I get is

```
method call sender=:1.242 -> dest=it.libersoft.FirmapiuDInterface serial=67 path=/it/libersoft/FirmapiuD; interface=it.libersoft.FirmapiuDInterface; member=sign
   array [
      variant          string "/home/svalo/programmi/devel/firmapiu-gui/pythondeps"
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "outdir"
         variant             string "/home/svalo/programmi/devel/firmapiu-gui"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "pin"
         variant             string "12345678"
      )
   ]
```

What i'd like to get is

```
method call sender=:1.242 -> dest=it.libersoft.FirmapiuDInterface serial=67 path=/it/libersoft/FirmapiuD; interface=it.libersoft.FirmapiuDInterface; member=sign
   array [
      string "/home/svalo/programmi/devel/libersoft/firmapiu-gui/pythondeps"
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "outdir"
         variant             string "/home/svalo/programmi/devel/libersoft/firmapiu-gui"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "pin"
         variant             string "12345678"
      )
   ]
```

**That is I expect python to send an array of strings and instead it sends an array of variants containing strings.**

The daemon devel wrote a simple client in java and it works honoring the signature

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [dbus-spec](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#idp61096272), the string-type is defined as follows:

> STRING 115 (ASCII 's') UTF-8 string (must be valid UTF-8). Must be nul terminated and contain no other nul bytes.

Which seems to imply that you should pass a UTF-8 encoded *bytes* object, rather than a unicode object.

**EDIT**:

You might need to pass this as a `QByteArray`:

```
QtCore.QByteArray(unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Ok, i tryed `arrfoo = bytearray('string', 'utf-8')` and calling result with `arrfoo` instead of filepath as a argument but it gives a `Marshalling failed: Unregistered type PyQt_PyObject passed in arguments` without even getting to dbus

Comment: @svalo. You might need to use a `QByteArray` (see my updated answer). I can't test this myself, so sorry for the guesswork. It seems strange that this is not handled automatically by PyQt - maybe there's a bug somewhere?

Comment: Ok, thanks . I tryed `foo='test'`,`test=QByteArray(foo.encode('utf-8'))`,`print(type(test)) -> <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray'>` , calling it with `result = self.fpiudaemon.call('sign', [test], options)` gives `Interface; member=sign
   array [
      variant          array of bytes "test"]` and so again not an array of string

Comment: @svalo. Well, my hunch is it's either a bug, or a very, very unintuitive API. From your original example, it's clear that PyQt is able to create non-variant strings, because they are used for dict entry keys. It just seems to be array *elements* and dict entry *values* that are converted to variants. I wonder whether string values outside of containers are also converted to variants? If not, it would seem to strongly suggest some kind of bug (or misfeature).

Comment: I succesfully send strings outside a container, dbus was seeing it as strings and not as variant strings so, yes, maybe you're right. I'll ask PyQt people

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, an answer appears!

You can specify the type signature of a dbus argument with `QDbusArgument`. Here's an example:

```py
filepath = QDBusArgument()
filepath.add(['/home/svalo/programmi/devel/pythondeps'], QMetaType.QStringList)
result = fpiudaemon.call('sign',filepath,options)
```

Obviously make sure that your data can be converted directly into the type you specified.

Comment: Don't post the same answer in several posts, instead you should mark the question as duplicate if you have the privileges.

Comment: I don't think I do. This question is the only result on Google for my queries around this issue so I wanted to make sure that anyone else who lands here gets the answer.

Comment: Well, for that, it is enough that you answer your own question since others will find your answer in the same way that you found this question.