# PyQt5 dbus: Force type signature of signal argument to be array of string

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, dbus

I'm writing an MPRIS player, which communicates with clients over
dbus. I need to emit a signal when my playback state changes. However,
the signal requires a format of `(sa{sv}as)`, and my code is producing
`(sa{sv}av)`. Here's the important part:

```py
self.signal = QDBusMessage.createSignal(
   "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
   "PropertiesChanged"
)
self.signal.setArguments(
    [interface, {property: values}, ['']]
)
```

The problem is the third item in the list given to setArguments. It is
an empty string in a list because I need to produce a type of 'array
of string' (`as`) but pyqt5 translates that into 'array of variant' (`av`).

I never need to put any actual data in that list, I just need the type
signature to be correct.

Is there any way to do this in PyQt5? Perhaps using QDBusArgument?

Comment: Have you tried using a `bytes` (or QByteArray) object? I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075484/how-to-pass-an-array-of-string-to-dbus-in-pyqt5) which was never set as accepted, but it's possible that it *was* a bug and it was solved in the meantime. Sorry, but I can't make a test program right now, but if you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by editing your question we'll try to dig into it better.

Comment: Hi @musicamante. Thanks for your reply. Passing a `QByteArray` ended up with a type signature of `y`, which is byte according to https://www.alteeve.com/w/List_of_DBus_data_types#BYTE . I found a seperate solution though, see the answer I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I... I got it working. Wow. That was a campaign.

I don't know what is going wrong exactly, I wasn't able to dig out of the PyQt5 source where exactly the conversion happens. However, I did look into `QDbusArgument()`. There is no documentation for this in python, and the C++ docs are worthless due to major differences, so I took to the source code. in `sip/QtDbus/qdbusargument.sip`, I discovered a *completely undocumented* new method called `qdbusargument_add`. This maps to `QDbusArgument().add()` in python. It is used to add arguments with an *explicit type id* to a `QDbusArgument`. And it has a *special case for `QStringList`*!

From then I just bruteforced every possibility I could think of with arguments to `QDbusArgument()`, and finally got the following:

```py
def PropertiesChanged(self, interface, property, values):
    """Sends PropertiesChanged signal through sessionBus.
    Args:
        interface: interface name
        property: property name
        values: current property value(s)
    """
    emptyStringListArg = QDBusArgument()
    emptyStringListArg.add([""], QMetaType.QStringList)
    self.signal.setArguments([interface, {property: values}, emptyStringListArg])
    QDBusConnection.sessionBus().send(self.signal)
```

It'd be great if the `add()` function could be documented, but I can't seem to send messages to the PyQt5 mailing list. Do I have to register first?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830032/where-to-report-pyqt5-bug

Comment: eyllanesc, thanks but as I said, I've tried to post to the pyqt mailing list before and my mail didn't go through.